# How to display specific cookie?

Tags: python, cookielib

I'm using ActivePython 2.5.1 and the cookielib package to retrieve web pages.

I'd like to display a given cookie from the cookiejar instead of the whole thing:

```
#OK to display all the cookies
for index, cookie in enumerate(cj):
    print index, '  :  ', cookie        

#How to display just PHPSESSID?
#AttributeError: CookieJar instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
print "PHPSESSID: %s" % cj['PHPSESSID']
```

I'm sure it's very simple but googling for this didn't return samples.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cookiejar does not have a dict-like interface, only iteration is supported. So you have to implement a lookup method yourself.

I am not sure what cookie attribute you want do do the lookup on. Example, using name:

```
def get_cookie_by_name(cj, name):
    return [cookie for cookie in cj if cookie.name == name][0]

cookie = get_cookie_by_name(cj, "PHPSESSID")
```

If you're not familiar with the `[...]` syntax, it is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The `[0]` then picks the first element of the list of matching cookies.